# Difference: "Come from beneath"/"Come from the beneath"

Tags: articles, adverbs

I've seen both "come from beneath" and "come from the beneath" being used. Are they both correct grammatically? If so, do they have different connotations?

Example from https://www.pressreader.com/nigeria/the-punch/20200905/281925955414191 :

> The fault had come from the beneath and it was not rectified.

Comment: "Come from the beneath" is not idiomatic in English. If you have seen it somewhere, please provide a link.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I've added an example

Comment: @xuhdef I went to that page and couldn't find the phrase "the beneath". Could you provide the entire sentence?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I've added the full sentence. You have to scroll to the right a bit and it is in the 6th column.

Comment: OK, got it. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole sentence at that link is

> The fault had come from the beneath and it was not rectified.

That is not idiomatic to me. "Beneath" is a preposition and not a noun, so it shouldn't have an article like "the".
These two sentences are idiomatic:

> The fault had come from the bottom.
> and
> The fault had come from beneath.

It may be that an editor intended to replace "the bottom" with "beneath", but did it incompletely.